# Variables with PostgreSQL on Heroku Dataclips

Tags: sql, postgresql, heroku, timestamp

I have a number of dataclips in Heroku (PostgreSQL) that call for a data range, over multiple relations. For data of the past week, I have something like the following query:

```
SELECT x, y, ts FROM (
  SELECT x1 as x, y1 as y, t1.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t1, t2
  WHERE ... t1.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8' day)::date
 UNION
  SELECT x2 as x, y2 as y, t3.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t3, t4
  WHERE ... t3.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '8' day)::date
 UNION
  ...(etc)...
) ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Is there a way to save a string like this as a variable, so to change the date range (ie "'8' day" -> "'366' day") over all queries I'd only need to change the string once rather than for each incidence? I've found some threads that say to declare the variable within a function, but for some reason nothing seems to work.

In heroku's docs it just says 'use standard SQL' - are functions / variables not a standard sql feature? Any advice appreciated, thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) to do something like this:

```
WITH vars AS (
  SELECT 
     interval '8' day AS "range"
)

SELECT x, y, ts FROM (
  SELECT x1 as x, y1 as y, t1.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t1, t2, vars
  WHERE ... t1.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - vars.range)::date
 UNION
  SELECT x2 as x, y2 as y, t3.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t3, t4
  WHERE ... t3.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - vars.range)::date
 UNION
  ...(etc)...
) ORDER BY ts DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in an SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION my_whatever_func(integer)
returns table(x integer, y integer, ts timestamp)
as $$
SELECT x, y, ts FROM (
  SELECT x1 as x, y1 as y, t1.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t1, t2
  WHERE ... t1.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval $1 day)::date
 UNION
  SELECT x2 as x, y2 as y, t3.mytimestamp as ts  
  FROM t3, t4
  WHERE ... t3.mytimestamp::date > (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval $1 day)::date
) ORDER BY ts DESC
$$ language sql;
```

and invoke with:

```
SELECT * FROM my_whatever_func(8);
```

This kind of query pattern suggests that you might want to be using table inheritance.

Comment: Unfortunately, from an email with heroku support: "You can't alter your database with a database, so the create function would have to be done with heroku pg:psql"